# Limitar quantidade de caracteres por coluna DataFrame Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

Preciso limitar a quantidade de caracteres por coluna no Dataframe para insert no SQL Server.

Exemplo:

Tenho um DataFrame com 3 colunas e 1k de linhas (Coluna J/ K/ L) e preciso limitar o insert desse DataFrame na tabela SQL com os seguintes parâmetros:

Coluna J com até 10 caracteres.
Coluna K com até 14 caracteres.
Coluna L com até 1 caracteres.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def c10(str):
    maxx = 10
    if len(str) > maxx:
        return str[:maxx]
    else:
        return str

def c14(str):
    maxx = 14
    if len(str) > maxx:
        return str[:maxx]
    else:
        return str

def c1(str):
    maxx = 1
    if len(str) > maxx:
        return str[:maxx]
    else:
        return str    

dic = { 'J' : ['JOE','JULIA','INFORMAÇÃO QUALQUER'],
        'K' : ['OUTRA COISA','KACCE','MAIS OUTRA SITUAÇÃO'],
        'L' : ['LEO','LUKE','LEVI'],
        'M' : ['MORGAN','MARIE',np.nan] }

data = pd.DataFrame(dic)    

data    

data['J'] = c10(data['J'])       
data['K'] = c14(data['K'])        
data['L'] = c1(data['L'])    

data
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Solução encontrada:

```
data['J'] = data['J'].str[:10]
data['K'] = data['K'].str[:14]
data['L'] = data['L'].str[:1]

data
```